# My python file is too heavy because of cv2 (like 50mo)

Tags: python, opencv

I got a python program that at some point needs to take a shot with the webcam 
So I used cv2 to take and store that shot but the file became too heavy even though im only using
cv2.VideoCapture() and imWrite()

How can I use only these two functions or is there any other way to take a shot from the webcam without having an extra 45mo?

Comment: what does _mo_ mean? Do you mean _mb_?

Answer (score 1):

using the following import statements instead of `import cv2`

```py
from cv2 import VideoCapture
from cv2 import imWrite
```

and then use the functions as `VideoCapture()` and `imWrite()`